# Getting the last line of a stream in PHP

Tags: php

I am using something similar to the code below to open a stream in PHP.

$output2 successfully is set to the response given by the client server for COMMAND2 if the response from COMMAND1 is a single line. However if the response from COMMAND1 is multi-line then $output2 is being set to line 2 of the response of COMMAND1 and not the last line in the stream (expected from COMMAND2).

```
$conn = stream_socket_client(
    $host.':'.$port,
    $errno,
    $errstr,
    $timeout
);

$host_confirm = fgets($conn);

fwrite($conn, 'COMMAND ');

$output1 = fgets($conn);

fwrite($conn, 'COMMAND2 ');

$output2 = fgets($conn);
```

So fgets() appears to moving a pointer down the stream line by line, my question is how can I always read the last line of the stream. If that is not possible can I erase the stream after the multi-line response so it doesn't affect the next call?

Comment: The solution is not "skip lines from the previous response" it's "correctly handle multiline responses". Whatever protocol you're talking to should have rules about denoting and handling multiline responses, and probably a reference implementation that show you exactly what to do.

Comment: I am expecting multi-lines that is fine, but I need to know how to avoid those responses altering the contents of fgets in subsequent calls or find an alternative to fgets. I could call fgets() x number of times according to the protocol for the multiline response but that seems a bit scrappy.

Comment: What I'm saying is that you don't have to worry about multiline responses "altering the contents" of subsequent calls if you're properly consuming them from the stream before issuing the next command.

Comment: is there any way to do that other than repeating fgets() for each line?

Comment: If not can I detect when the end of the file is reached?

Answer (score 0):

try something like this one:

```
    <?php

    $host = 'localhost';
    $socket = fsockopen($host, 80, $no, $err, 30);

    if (!$err) {
        fwrite($socket, 'random text');

//wait for end
        while (!feof($socket)) {
            echo fgets($socket, 4096);

            fwrite($socket, 'COMMAND');

            fwrite($socket, 'COMMAND2');

        }

        fclose($socket);
    }
```

:)